# Mongodb c# can't parse near/geoquery

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

When trying to parse this query

```
Query.Near("coordinates", 58, 8, 100000));
```

In c# I get his error message:

```
Command 'count' failed: exception: can't parse query (2dsphere): 
{ $near: [ 58.1453,     7.9571 ], $maxDistance: 100000.0 } 
(response: { "errmsg" : "exception: can't parse query   
(2dsphere): { $near: [ 58.1453, 7.9571 ], $maxDistance: 100000.0 }",
"code" : 16535, "ok" : 0.0 })
```

If i try to parse the following query in shell

```
db.docs.find({coordinates : { $near : { type : "Point" , coordinates : [ 58, 8 ] },   
$maxDistance : 100 } }  )
```

it gets parsed. So what I'm wondering is how can I structure the working query in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't reproduce the problem. What versions of MongoDB and the MongoDB driver are you using?

Comment: Driver, 1.83
Database, 2.49

Also, What's the difference between Query.Near and Query.Near<TCoordinates> and how do I structure a C# query with Near<TCoordinates>?